# Problems with Impala. "Query waiting to be closed"

Tags: cloudera, impala

I have a little problems with my Impala´s Platform.  We I try to do a query, sometimes I get a time out, and when reviewed the logs, I saw that I got almost 4000 querys waiting to be closed.
I am using CDH 5.14 and impala 2.11. 
Someone know if are there any bugs on the system, about queries?. Or Do I need to configure any parameters on the system to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you decrease
`--idle_query_timeout` and `--idle_session_timeout`

Comment: I get this same behavior from HUE. Some connections are not closed when the tab is closed. I don't recall the exact state, but we have the idle_query_timeout and idle_session_timeout set to 1 hour and these are closed after that time. So if idle_query isn't working try idle_session. If that doesn't work, there maybe something going one with your specific setup.

Ref: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Query-Cancel-and-idle-query-timeout-is-not-working/td-p/58104